# Pretty print array object, not array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, pretty-print

So, I've already discovered

```
Arrays.toString(arr);
```

So don't point me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java).

My problem is just a tiny bit different. In this case, I don't have a native array pointer to the array in question. I have it as an Object pointer, and it could be an array of any type (primitive or otherwise). In this case, I can use the above toString() method by casting the Object pointer to Object[]. However, if the pointer is a primitive array, it will throw a runtime exception and crash. So?

Example:

```
double test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Object t = test;
// Now how do I pretty print t as an array with no access to test?
```

I solved my problem with this:

```
public String unkObjectToString(Object o) {
    if(!o.getClass().isArray()) return o.toString();
    int len = Array.getLength(o);
    String ret = "[";
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        Object q = Array.get(o, i);
        ret += unkObjectToString(q);
        if(i == len - 1)
            ret += "]";
        else
            ret += ", ";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to test and cast.

```
if (o instanceof byte[]) {
      return Arrays.toString((byte[]) o);
} //etc.
```

You could do this via reflection, but it would not be any cleaner in the end, although it would be a few lines of code less.

Comment: I was praying to the holy god of programming that this could be avoided, and StackOverflow was my last resort. I will perform this abomination now, but know that my soul is proffered to the depths of hell along with the coming committal. Peace upon you, brother. *salute*

Comment: Dramatics aside, why does this bother you so much?  10 lines of extra code is enough to make you feel you've lost your innocence?  That primitives are not objects is a core reality in Java.  If this bothers you that much, well, get over it or choose another language.

Comment: It mostly bothers me because the code I'm working in has it's fair share of if-else chains 1000 lines long that could have easily been avoided but are now ingrained in the project and I was hoping to avoid adding a link to the chains. I fixed it with a recursive function (to help with nested arrays) similar to what Bozho's library function would have done. I will add this function to my question for reference and critiques.

Answer (score 2):

[`ArrayUtils.toString(arrayObj)`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%29) ([commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)) - does exactly what you want (also handles multi-dimensional arrays). Simply download the commons-lang jar and add it to your classpath.

Comment: While I cannot import your faithful observance, my task is now to reincarnate the spirit of your suggestion as best as I am allowed by the laws of nature.

Comment: why you can't import it? download commons-lang, add it to classpath, and you are done

Comment: Either because Jordan can't use additional libraries or because commons-lang may be incompatible with the version of the JDK that Jordan is using. Are there really that many people still using 1.3?